# How to create a new page in alchemy-cms?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, alchemy-cms

My plan is to create a new  page in alchemy-cms, i did the following steps,

```
  1. # config/alchemy/page_layouts.yml 
- name: contact 
  cache: false 
  unique: false 
  elements: [headline, contactform, text] 
  autogenerate: [headline, contactform]

  2. rails g alchemy:page_layouts --skip
```

How to display this page on  Alchemy-cms backend ?

Answer (score 4):

1. Restart the server with "bin/rails server"
2. log in as admin
3. go to pages
4. on the right side of "index" you can add a new subpage
5. Then choose your page, in your case "contact" and add.